# How to run Solr inside Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, solr, setup-deployment

I have to work with [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/), which I'll use from another webapp to index and search documents.
I thought I could run an instance of it inside Eclipse, alongside my web application, but if I import the Solr war, Eclipse will unpack it in a web project.
Is there a way to keep it as a War and just have it deployer inside a Tomcat server instance (in the IDE)?

Or is there a better (easier) way to do what I want to do? Basically I want a running instance of Solr to which I can connect and operate from the web application I'm developing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are keeping our Solr configurations together with the according war file within an Eclipse project. I will refer to this project as `your project here`. That way we keep everything together in one place

- the war file
- the index
- the configurations

---

What you need to do is

1) Create an empty tomcat server within eclipse

2) Add `-Dsolr.solr.home=${resource_loc:/<your project here>/solr/home}` to the VM arguments of that tomcat

[image]

3) Add the solr war file as `<Context>` to the server.xml of that tomcat
[image]

Comment: Uuuh... really precious, thank you! I didn't get completely how it works, but it's working, and that's what matters to me now.